# Your application will be deployed only on the device specified by the provided index or identifier

Tags: angular, angular-cli, nativescript, tns

When I try `tns run android Pixel_2_API_29` I get the following error:

> Your application will be deployed only on the device specified by the
>   provided index or identifier. Unable to apply changes on device:
>   emulator-5554. Error is: The current version of
>   nativescript-dev-webpack (1.0.0) is not compatible with the used CLI:
>   5.4.2. Please upgrade your NativeScript CLI version (npm i -g nativescript)..

As I am a new learner and wanted to convert a NativeScript project that is written in 2017 with version 5 or 6 to version 8, I changed many of files and seems everything is OK, but I don't know why do I get this error when I want to run on the emulator?

I don't know which file of project I must looking for this error inside of it? Let me know to put that file's content here.

I also tried `npm i -g nativescript` but still get the same error.

EDIT: I went to root of my project where the `node_modules` folder exist. Then tried this command `>npm i nativescript-dev-webpack@latest --save-dev ./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --deps --configs` and got this result:

```
npm ERR! code ENOLOCAL
npm ERR! Could not install from "node_modules\.bin\update-ns-webpack" as it does not contain a package.json file.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\m\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2019-07-13T11_27_04_487Z-debug.log
```

I searched for `update-ns-webpack` in the mentionad directory inside my project and I found it there. I also found another file named `update-ns-webpack.cmd`. The contents of them are:

`update-ns-webpack`:

```
#!/bin/sh
basedir=$(dirname "$(echo "$0" | sed -e 's,\\,/,g')")

case `uname` in
    *CYGWIN*) basedir=`cygpath -w "$basedir"`;;
esac

if [ -x "$basedir/node" ]; then
  "$basedir/node"  "$basedir/../nativescript-dev-webpack/bin/update-ns-webpack" "$@"
  ret=$?
else 
  node  "$basedir/../nativescript-dev-webpack/bin/update-ns-webpack" "$@"
  ret=$?
fi
exit $ret
```

And `update-ns-webpack.cmd`:

```
@IF EXIST "%~dp0\node.exe" (
  "%~dp0\node.exe"  "%~dp0\..\nativescript-dev-webpack\bin\update-ns-webpack" %*
) ELSE (
  @SETLOCAL
  @SET PATHEXT=%PATHEXT:;.JS;=;%
  node  "%~dp0\..\nativescript-dev-webpack\bin\update-ns-webpack" %*
)
```

EDIT2: I updated my webpack with the above commands(the problem was that I should not use `.` in Windows command line to execute a script file), but still I get the same error when I try `tns run android --device Pixel_2_API_29`.

I uploaded my project here: https://github.com/rezaee/confusion-last . Please take a look at them, maybe you can find the problem?

Comment: Did you follow the upgrade instructions? Did you update [webpack to latest](https://docs.nativescript.org/releases/upgrade-instructions#upgrading-webpack)?

Comment: @Manoj: What is this line of code `./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --deps --configs`? How should I run it?

Comment: Just as it's from your project root, it updates dependencies and webpack config to latest.

Comment: @Manoj May you write what exactly should I run in CMD? I tried `npm i nativescript-dev-webpack@latest --save-dev ./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --deps --configs` inside my project root but didn't work.

Comment: We would need something more than **it didn't work**, please elaborate what errors you see.

Comment: @Manoj: Please read the `EDIT2` part of my question, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I have downloaded your code from your github and realised that you are using  "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^1.0.0" that is still a release candidate and not compatiable with your other dependencies. I have uninstalled that and re-installed the stable version and everything works fine.

Run the following commands to the above

```
npm uninstall nativescript-dev-webpack --save-dev
npm install nativescript-dev-webpack --save-dev
```

This will install  version 0.24.1 to your project and will add that to your package.json as well. "nativescript-dev-webpack": "^0.24.1"

Update the webpack config after that.

```
./node_modules/.bin/update-ns-webpack --configs
```

Now run `tns debug android --bundle`

P.S. Although it shows some error because all the files are not there, may be you have forgotten to commit e.g. './about.component.css' and './contact.component.css' , ./favorites.component.css etc.